# Error configuring OpenFaas - can't connect to nats://nats.openfaas.svc.cluster.local:4222

Tags: openfaas

$ kubectl logs queue-worker-5d86f844f-86vg7 -n openfaas --tail=100 -f
Loading basic authentication credentials
Connect: nats://nats.openfaas.svc.cluster.local:4222
can't connect to nats://nats.openfaas.svc.cluster.local:4222: nats: no servers available for connection
panic: can't connect to nats://nats.openfaas.svc.cluster.local:4222: nats: no servers available for connection

Comment: Hi there, i see it has been a while, but, are you still having trouble? If yes, how did you install OpenFaas (helm, arkade, other)? Are you using NATS that comes with OpenFaas, or a separate instance (it looks like you're using the NATS that comes with OpenFaas)? You may want to try this to see if it helps you: https://blog.alexellis.io/tls-the-easy-way-with-openfaas-and-k3sup/